# Java: Array List Printing object reference instead of array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm am very much a rookie when it comes to coding. What I'm trying to accomplish is to load grades from a txt file and put them into an existing array.

I have actually solved this. and In the program the array does retain the values. But when I got to print them I get the object reference aka [I@5c647e05 rather than the array. Below is my code.

```
   public static void main(String[] args)    {
        int[] list = new int[15];
        Scanner in = null; // create a scanner object
        loadGrades(in, list);

        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public static void loadGrades(Scanner in, int[] list) {

        int grades; // int variable
        try { // try            
            in = new Scanner(new FileReader("Proj5Data.txt"));// change filename
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { // catch
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {         
                grades = in.nextInt(); // var
                list[i] = grades ;// put the int in the array at the counter value            
        }
        in.close();

    }
```

Print results as:

```
[I@5c647e05
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print an array behind the scenes the method `toString()` is being called and it doesn't print the content of the array (which is too bad IMO). But you can easily get over it using the library `Arrays`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't print the contents of a list like that in Java.  You need to loop over the contents of the array and print them individually.

```
for(int i : list){
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(list) uses a .toString() method to resolve what to print.
You can either use Arrays.toString(list) or print it one by one.

Answer (score -1):

So All the methods you guys gave me did indeed work. But I ended up just using printf to print them out. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Please do not use answers to post things that should be comments.